# How to add brand description in Magento

Tags: magento

I have used this [Manufacturer brand logo extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manufacturer-brand-logo.html) to display my brands in product page.This extension list out all the brand logo i have uploaded along with the title in manufacturer page.This extension don't have the option to add brand description.What i need to do add brand description by using this extension and make it to display in manufacturer page.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can either use any other extension that allows to add **description** OR you can add an additional field called '**description**' in the existing module, make DB changes for description field and on frontend you can print the description. For ex: `$this->getDescription();`